# Getting list of blobs (artifacts) exported as part of failed export operation

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We can very much get a list of exported artifacts using `.show operation <OperationId> details`. But this only works for the export operation which succeeded. Let's say we have an export operation which ran for some time and exported some blobs but then failed due to some issue , is there a way to get list of these blobs exported as a result of this half baked export operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately this information is not available.